# Expansion for $\cos(nx)$, with $n \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: trigonometry, polynomials

Is there an expansion for $\cos(nx)$ when $n$ is not an integer?
I'm trying to rewrite the following equation

Equation = $cos(nx_{1}) + cos(nx_{2}) + cos(nx_{3}) + ... + cos(nx_{600})$

as

Equation = ***factor*** $[cos(x_{1}) + cos(x_{2}) + cos(x_{3}) + ... + cos(x_{600})]$

Comment: Not in general.  There are some special cases like $n=\frac12$ where there are formulas.

Comment: Technically, I think you can do it for most rational numbers. But it's going to get ugly for all but the simplest ones.

Comment: If there is a $p$ such that $0<p<1$ and there is an expression of $\cos\left(px\right)$, then for any integers $n$, there must have an expression of $\cos\left(n+p\right)x$

Comment: What type of expansion are you talking about here? A power series? An expansion into a polynomial in the cosine and sine of $x$?

Comment: @Allawonder, I have this situation:

Result = cos(nx1) + cos(nx2) + cos(nx3) + cos(nx4) + ... + cos(nx600)

and I'm looking for a way of writing Result as

Result = factor*[cos(x1) + cos(x2) + cos(x3) + cos(x4) + ... + cos(x600)]

Comment: @CamiloDamasceno It's better to put the exact problem you want to solve in the body of the question, as that may likely be seen by potential helpers. Also, a reason for why you want to make such a form might suggest other ways to achieve the same thing. So it's always best to ask for exactly what you want *with as much context as possible.* The better composed your question, the more likely it is to receive appropriate attention.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is no such expansion. Indeed, any polynomial expression in $\cos(x)$ and $\sin(x)$ will be $2\pi$-periodic. But if $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ is not an integer, then $x \mapsto \cos(\alpha x)$ is not $2\pi$-periodic, hence it cannot be rewritten as a polynomial in $\cos(x)$ and $\sin(x)$.

Now, if you allow roots of polynomials then, by writing $\cos(x) = T_n(\cos(x/n))$ (with $T_n$ the Chebychev polynomial), we can express $\cos(x/n)$ as a root of $T_n - \cos(x)$ (which manageable for $n=2$ but gets complicated fast).